# How to build links in c# mvc4 with REST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to the use of REST. The documentation I found about MVC 4 and REST tells me every time the same. The build is --> www.example.com/{controller}/{id} 
This is the basic layout of REST. I will explain my case first:

a company has many departments, and a department has many contacts.

The webapp starts with a login of a contact. Once the user is logged in, at this moment I create a session for this user. When the contact starts browsing, should my link be www.example.com/userid?

When the user is logged in he can create a new meeting for himself. What would the link be then? I thought --> www.example.com/meeting --> post

After the postmethod I go to my controller of meeting with

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Meeting(Meetingmodel model)
```

In this action I get the session of the user and bind him with the meeting.
Is this the right way? If it isn't any good links / tutorials?

When is it allowed in REST to use parameters? www.example.com/?category=something

If have looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

but there is nothing about creating an object as a logged in person.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll start explaining it simply, but you got me a bit confused.

First, is storing the user id in session the right way to do it ? Short answer, yes it is. You should not include your current user id in the url.

Now, let's say you want an url to display meetings due on monday. The url will be the following :

www.{yoursite}.com/meeting/monday.
To handle this, in your Meeting Controller, just add the following Action Method:

public ActionResult Meeting(string dayOfWeek)

Since you have the currently logged in user id, in your session object, you can easily request your database to look for the meetings, with the current user id, and with the dayOfWeek.

This way, parts of your url ARE in fact your action method parameters. So no need of the {url}/?{parameters} syntax.

Is that helping you ?

Comment: Yes it does, but what happens when I need to add a contact to a companydepartment for example? What will the controller look like then? I was thinking of something like www.example.com/company/12/department/ or would it be simply www.example.com/department? If it would be my first suggestion it is just like u have a controller inside a controller... How to handle this? Thx for answering Miiite

Comment: The REST Url syntaxe is usefull to display pages, since, as I explained previously, the parameter parsing is automatic.
But to POST a form, you don't use this sintax. Simply call the {website}/controller/Department, with your form posted.
In your Department Action Method of your controller, add a Model in parameter. Your form should be built on a Model, so you will get back your model when submiting it. No need for special syntax in that case